# Docker Compose Nginx Link containers

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, docker-compose

I have a docker compose container that runs Nginx.  The site hosted is just a .test domain, like `example.test`.

Also in the container Nginx runs a location proxy and redirects it to `example.test:8000`.  But it's not able to connect to that because that's actually being hosted from a different container on the same system (all bridged networks).

How can I let the containers communicate using `example.test` domain?

Or if I can't get them to communicate via `example.test` then how can I link them so they can use their docker-compose service name such as `api` or `frontend`?

Docker compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        ports:
         - "5432:5432"
    django:
        build: ./api
        command: ["./docker_up.sh"]
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./api:/app/api
          - api-static:/app/api/staticfiles
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
          - db
        environment:
          - MODE=DEV

volumes:
  frontend-build:
  api-static:
  certificates:
```

2nd compose file (run together):

```
version: '3'

services:
    django:
        environment:
          - MODE=PROD
        #links:
        #  - hosting
    hosting:
        build: ./hosting
        restart: always
        network_mode: bridge
        volumes:
           - frontend-build:/var/www
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
        environment:
          - MODE=PROD
        #links:
        #  - django

volumes:
    frontend-build:
```

With these current settings I get an error when I run it

> ERROR: for 92b89f848637_opensrd_hosting_1  Cannot start service hosting: Cannot link to /opensrd_django_1, as it does not belong to the default network

Edit:  Altered docker-compose.prod.yml:

```
networks:
    app_net:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
              -
                subnet: 172.16.238.0/24

services:
    django:
        environment:
          - MODE=PROD
        networks:
            app_net:
            ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10
```

But this gives me an error.

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.prod.yml' is invalid because:
>
> networks.app_net value Additional properties are not allowed ('config' was unexpected)
>
> networks.app_net.ipam contains an invalid type, it should be an object

Answer (score 1):

So I tried the options given by @trust512 and @DimaL, and those didn't work.

However after deleting the network and links from my compose files, and removing the existing default network and built containers, it worked, and I can not refer between container using `db`, `django`, and `hosting`.

The only thing different is I changed the composer version from 3 to 3.5.

These are the final files for anyone interested:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        ports:
         - "5432:5432"
    django:
        build: ./api
        command: ["./docker_up.sh"]
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./api:/app/api
          - api-static:/app/api/staticfiles
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
          - db
        environment:
          - MODE=DEV

volumes:
  frontend-build:
  api-static:
```

docker-compose.prod.yml:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
    django:
        environment:
          - MODE=PROD
    hosting:
        build: ./hosting
        restart: always
        volumes:
           - frontend-build:/var/www
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
        environment:
          - MODE=PROD

volumes:
    frontend-build:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `external_links` (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external_links) or try to put all containers on the same virtual network.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you just want them (django and nginx) to be linked across composes?

Then **a native solution** would be to use **external_links** exampled [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external_links)
And use it like this:

```
services:
    [...]
    hosting:
        [...]
        external_links:
          - django_1:example
        [...]
```

Where `django_1` stands for the container name created by the compose you provided and `example` is the alias that the container will be visible inside Django container.

**Other way round** you can just point a **example.test** domain to a specific address by editing your `/etc/hosts` (provided you work on linux/mac)
for example by adding a record like

```
172.16.238.10   example.test
```

Where the address above would point to your django application (container).

The above can be achieved without altering your `/etc/hosts` by using native solution from compose (`extra_hosts`) documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts)

Additionally if you prefer a static ip address for your django/nginx containers in case you stick to the `/etc/hosts` od `extra_hosts` solution you can utilize another native solution provided by compose that sets up a static ip for a chosen services, properly exampled [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address)

A adjusted listing from the linked documentation:

```
services:
  [...]
  django:
    [...]
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10

networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      -
        subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
```

Comment: When I try external_links, I get the same error I had before `Cannot start service hosting: Cannot link to /opensrd_django_1, as it does not belong to the default network`.  As for the network, can I just randomly specify my own IP as long as it's within range the subnet?